# webpack 1.js 2.js. For using this command you need to install "1.js"

Tags: webpack, installation, webpack-cli

It's my first time to learn and use webpack. This problem might be too easy even though I have tried to google it for couple of hours.

My problem is about to make a package of a js file within webpack.

The webpack has been installed globally.

I can check the version by using:

```
webpack -v
```

the response is:

```
webpack 5.11.0
webpack-cli 4.3.0
```

Then I use the command learnt from website to pack 1.js:

```
webpack 1.js 2.js
```

Instead of getting it packed, the message is:

```
[webpack-cli] For using this command you need to install: '1.js' package
? Would you like to install '1.js' package? (That will run 'npm install -D 1.js') (Y/n) › true
```

I also tried:

```
webpack 1.js -o 2.js
```

The response will be the same as above.

It's really driving me crazy.

Answer (score 0):

There's a bug in version 4.3.0 of webpack-cli, use version 4.2.0

https://github.com/webpack/webpack-cli/issues/2266